# VB - Convert long String-number to Integer

Tags: vb.net

Alright, so I'm not exactly very oriented when it comes to functions available in VB.
I have a string containing the current date and time and need to convert it to a integer so i can compare the time.

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_int as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(my_str)
```

I cant do that with this string apparently. Because I think it is too long for the 32-bit integer. All the other convertions I have tried also fails. That including "ToInt64", "Int", "CInt"... So, any idea how to convert this longer string to an integer?

Comment: I found out by doing some testing that an integer can't actually hold a number any longer than 10 digits!
So, what is another data type for long ints then is the new question?
EDIT: No decimals if possible

Comment: What's wrong with decimals?

Comment: Why convert to numeric at all?  The whole reason why date/times are usually formatted like that is so that you can just do simple string comparisons on them.  I'm not saying it was necessarily a good idea to format them like that, but as long as they are already formatted that way, you might as well just compare them as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just simply use `Date`? You can compare `Dates` with each other, so there's no need to use an integer for comparing.

```
Dim my_date as Date = DateTime.ParseExact(my_str, "yyyyMMddhhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not very oriented around what options existing. So I just go with what I find first.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

*Normally I wouldn't do this.  Several correct answers have already been given, but since you are still learning VB.NET, I feel like a more thorough answer would be helpful to you.  So my answer will repeat some of what others have already said.*

The `Int64` and `Decimal` types are indeed big enough to to hold a number like that.  I suspect that the reason why `Convert.ToInt64` wasn't working for you is because you were trying to store the results in an `Integer` variable, like this:

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_int as Integer = Convert.ToInt64(my_str)  ' Throws an OverflowException
```

The reason that fails is not because `ToInt64` doesn't work.  That part of the statement is actually working fine.  The part that's failing is where you are assigning the `my_int` variable to the value.  `my_int` is declared as an `Integer`.  The `Integer` type in VB.NET is actually just a pseudonym for `Int32`.  In other words, it's actually the same thing as this:

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_int as Int32 = Convert.ToInt64(my_str)  ' Throws an OverflowException, just like the above example
```

To correct the problem, you need to change the type of the `my_int` variable to `Int64` so that it will be big enough to hold the value being returned from the `ToInt64` function.

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_int as Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(my_str)  ' Works
```

In VB.NET, `Long` is the pseudonym for `Int64`, so in most cases, that's what you should use.  If you are going to use `Long`, however, using the `ToInt64` method is a little ugly.  It would be easier to read to just use `Long` on both sides of the assignment, like this:

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_int as Long = Long.Parse(my_str)  ' Works, just like above
```

That also makes the code marginally safer because it will still work even if the size of `Long` changes in the future (however unlikely that may be).

The `Decimal` type would also be large enough to hold the value, but it would be less efficient than using `Long`, so I wouldn't recommend it.

This begs the question, however, *"Why are you doing this?"*  If you need to compare the value to another `Long` variable, it would make sense to do that, but then how did you get that other `Long` value?  If you are converting both `Long` values from strings, then it doesn't make sense to do that.  The string is already formatted in a way where it can be easily compared with other strings of the same format.  For instance:

```
Dim dateTime1 As String = "201308281110"
Dim dateTime2 As String = "201308281850"
If dateTime1 > dateTime2 Then
    ' Doesn't get here
End If
If dateTime1 < dateTime2 Then
    ' Get's here
End If
If dateTime1 = dateTime2 Then
    ' Doesn't get here
End If
```

If, however, you need to parse the value to read its individual parts (e.g. date, time, year, month, hour), it makes more sense to convert the value to a `DateTime` value.  Or, if you need to compare the string value to another value which is already stored in a `DateTime` variable, then, in that case, it also makes sense to convert the string to a `DateTime` value.  In VB.NET, the pseudonym for `DateTime` is simply `Date`, so in most cases, you should just use that, like this:

```
Dim my_str as String = "201308281110"
Dim my_date as Date = Date.ParseExact(my_str, "yyyyMMddHHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
If my_date > Date.Now Then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

But `Long.Parse` works as well as `Convert.ToInt64` since it doesn't overflow([`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) is 2147483647):

```
Dim myLong1 = Long.Parse("201308281110")
Dim myLong2 = System.Convert.ToInt64("201308281110")
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/oAmUy9)</kbd>

Note that  [`Long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx) is the same as `Int64`.

Comment: You failed to mention the reason why it was overflowing for him.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: I assumed that he already knows the reason because he mentioned: _"I think it is too long for the 32-bit integer"_. I also mentioned that _"long doesn't overflow"_. **Edit** However, edited my answer.

Comment: Don't you need Option Infer On for that to work as I assume you intend? (I like Option Infer On; some people are enthusiastically opposed to it.)

Comment: Yes, Option Infer On is always my default setting. It's not the same as Option Strict Off, because the variable is strongly-typed, it's just inferred implicitly (like the C# `var`) keyword. So i omit the type if it's obvious.